# Dowload word document with costum name using laravel8 , ajax and PhpWord Library

Tags: ajax, laravel, phpword

I'm trying to download a Word document from storage path using Laravel8 and Ajax call.

I'm using the following code:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.download', function(){

       var data = '';
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log(id);
       var data = '';
          
       $.ajax({
          
             url:"modeles_contrat/"+id+"/download",
          
             type:"GET",
             data: data, 

             xhrFields: { 
                 responseType: 'blob' 
             }, 
 
             success: function(response) {  
                var blob = new Blob([response]); 
                var link = document.createElement('a'); 
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
                link.download = "casting.docx"; 
                link.click(); 
             }, 

             error: function() {
                $('#responseMsg').removeClass("alert-success");
                $('#responseMsg').addClass("alert-danger");
                $('#responseMsg').html('Veuillez générer le contrat');
                $('#responseMsg').show();
             }
            })
           });
</script>
```

And the following controller :

```
public function download($id, $downloadName = null) {
     $data2 = array();
              
     $data_modele = Model_Contrat::where('id_modele_contrat',$id)->first();

     $filename= $data_modele->fichier;
     $filepath = 'Casting_V0.1_Test\casting\storage\app\public\uploads\modeles_contrat/'.$filename;

     /*  $filepath = str_replace('', '/',public_path('Model/'.$filename.'.docx'));
*/

     if (file_exists($filepath)) {
         $headers = array(
                  'Content-Type: application/docx',
         );

         $downloadName = $downloadName??$filename;
         return Response::download($filepath);
     } else {
         $data2['success'] = 2;
         $data2['message'] = 'File not uploaded.'; 
                       
         return response()->json($data2);
     }
}
```

All works file , but the problem is all the files are downloaded with the name `casting.docx`. I want to download each file with its original name and not with the name `casting.docx`.

If you have any idea about how I can download files with custom name help me.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I tried to remove the ajax call , So I'm using the following code :

I my datatable I added a column link to get the id of the row:

```
$button .='<a href="/modeles_contrat/"'.$data->id_modele_contrat.'"/download" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" data_id="'.$data->id_modele_contrat.'" >Télécharger</a>';
```

And in my route I have the following route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:account_manager|admin|manager_de_filiale']], function() { 
    Route::get('/modeles_contrat/{id_modele_contrat}/download', [App\Http\Controllers\ModeleController::class, 'download']);
});
```

And in my controller I have the following code :

```
public function download($id_modele_contrat) {
    $data2 = array();
    $data_modele = Model_Contrat::where('id_modele_contrat',$id_modele_contrat)->first();

    $filename = $data_modele->fichier;
    $filepath = 'Casting_V0.1_Test\casting\storage\app\public\uploads\modeles_contrat/'.$filename;

    /*  $filepath = str_replace('', '/',public_path('Model/'.$filename.'.docx'));
*/

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: => application/docx',
        );
        return Response::download($filepath,$filename, $headers);
    }
}
```

So now when I click on the link to download file I get the following page and the file doesn't downloaded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the filename as a second argument to the `Response::download()` function.
Try:

```
return Response::download($filepath, $downloadName);
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files) is the documentation for the download function (`Storage::download` and `Response::download` should be the same).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but doesn't work , please check my update , I tried to remove the ajax call , but I get alwayd an error

Comment: It seems like you opened '/modeles_contrat' but your route is '/modeles_contrat/{id_modele_contrat}/download'. So you opened the wrong route, right?

Comment: yes exactly but where is the error in my code ?

Comment: It works now I chaged the link to  `$button .='<a href="/modeles_contrat/'.$data->id_modele_contrat.'/download" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" data_id="'.$data->id_modele_contrat.'" >Télécharger</a>';`